# Retrieve data nsdata from the sqlite database and view them in a webView

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I have stored in my local database (sqlite3) the html page taken from webview. I memorized it all as nsdata.
Add, I want the page saved in the database to appear in another webview.

My code is:

```
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from offRss 
where idRss=%d", self.recordIDToEdit];

// Load the relevant data.
NSArray *results = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.dbManager loadDataFromDB:query]];

// Set the loaded data to the textfields.
NSData *URL;
URL = [[results objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:[self.dbManager.arrColumnNames indexOfObject:@"body"]];

NSString *stringa=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:URL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",URL);


[self.webView loadHTMLString:stringa baseURL:nil];
```

But this method does not work. It gives me an error:

```
-[__NSCFString bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 
0xf50a000
2017-07-20 07:46:26.160 prova2[4788:70b] *** Terminating app due to 
uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-
 [__NSCFString bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 
 0xf50a000'
```

I'm reporting the line error:
     NSString *stringa=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:URL 
    encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the value for stringa?

Comment: What is the value for stringa and also value for URL?

Comment: URL contains the html page stored in the database as nsdata, but the stringa is the variable I declare to cast from NSData to NSString to print them in the webView.

Comment: The error indicates that your `URL` variable is actually an `NSString`, not an `NSData`. This means your `results` array doesn't contain the objects you think it does.

Comment: @rmaddy how to fix?

Comment: You need to either fix the data being returned by your `loadDataFromDB:` method or you need to fix this code to deal with `results` already containing `NSString` and not `NSData`.

Comment: @rmaddy my `loadDataFromDB` is `(NSArray *)loadDataFromDB:(NSString *)query{
    [self runQuery:[query UTF8String] isQueryExecutable:NO];
        return (NSArray *)self.arrResults;
}` :O :O

Comment: have you confirmed that the store operation is correct? ie-test it with a trivial web page, then check the db manually to see if the stored object is correct.