# Convert NSData location memory to NSString

Tags: objective-c, foundation

In my application, extract an element saved as NSData from a SQlite database.

I have:

```
NSData * results = [result objectAtIndex:0];
```

Where is the array where the data is downloaded from the database. I'm sure the query works because if I write:

```
NSLog(@"%@, results");
```

I print so many numbers like:

<3c346535 4535677 2948929 298289fc>

> (Many times, so I suppose the memory addresses of the NSData element
>   I  saved)

Now, I want to convert these memory locations in string, to view the
 content and do it with:

```
NSString * html = [[NSString allocation] initWithData:results encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

And then:

```
NSLog (@"%@,html");
```

At this point the program crash on the line:

```
NSString * html = [[NSString allocation] initWithData: results encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

And the error is:

> __NSArrayM bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8b8a650 2017-07-20 10:41:34.755 prova2[6598:70b] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM
>   bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8b8a650'

Why?

Comment: Are you sure you are not mixing up `result` (the `NSArray`) and `results` (the `NSData`)? The error your getting is because you're passing an array to the initializer.

Comment: @MeanDinosaur I did not understand very well what you mean

Comment: Are you working with the (or are you the same) person that posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45221939/convert-nsdata-location-memory-to-nsstring The questions are very similar.

Comment: you have linked my post

Comment: The error is telling you that `results` passed in this line:
`[[NSString allocation] initWithData: results encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];` is an `NSArray`, not an `NSData`. In your code `result` is an `NSArray`. Are you sure you should pass `results` instead of `result`?

Comment: Sorry, wrong link. I meant this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45218283/retrieve-data-nsdata-from-the-sqlite-database-and-view-them-in-a-webview

Comment: I'll work on this upon seeing a good answer to @rmaddy's question.

Comment: Do you mean `NSLog(@"%@", html);`?  `NSLog(@"%@,html");` doesn't really make sense.